# Django Admin show value to 2 decimal places

Tags: django-admin

I need to control how many decimal places of a value are shown in the Django admin. So far I can only find documentation for database representations. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I have found that Django does not offer built in control over float output precision. I simply had to write a function that controls the output of the value and specify how it is returned, i.e:

```
def some_output(self, obj):
    return "%.xf" % obj.to_display
```

Where "x" is the precision and "to_display" is the value from the db.

Comment: also see [admin display decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display)

Comment: Use "%.2f" for float